# Wordpress won't allow PHP errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site I am working on currently that uses Wordpress.  However it makes it a bit difficult to debug because I cannot get PHP errors to display on the page.  Instead I get the white screen of death.

I have tried adding the defines in the wp-config.php file and in the php.ini file to no avail.  I also can't add the flags in the .htaccess because of the way the server handles apache/php.

One thing I noticed is that any page outside of Wordpress displays errors fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding `ini_set("display_errors","2");` `ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);` to the `index.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

Can you get access to /var/log/httpd/error_log?  If you're on Linux, this is (by default) where the errors would be shown.

Comment: Its hosted (privately) so I have no access to /var.  Thanks

Comment: OK, how about the error plugin? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/error-reporting/

Comment: check your installation's root for error_log file or the plugin's root that causes the error..some servers are configured that way.

Comment: @Scott, the error-reporting came a bit closer.  I actually have errors but I'm still not getting the errors from the main problem.  The problematic code is some utility functions file inside a subdirectory of wp-content

Answer (score 1):

on the .htaccess file in your root directory add the following line.

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very useful for development WordPress installation set to true WP_DEBUG constant in wp-config.php file:

```
/**
* For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
*
* Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
* It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
* in their development environments.
*/

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

You will see much more, including PHP noticing and WordPress messages about deprecating staff usage.

Comment: This is one of the first things we tried.  Thank you though. I'm thinking something is conflicting.